# Error: stale element reference: element is not attached

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I know this is duplicated question but as in others posts I added delay (10 secs) and it is not working. I dont understand why it is not working because it is being extracted first then used to scroll inside the container. The code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep, time
from parsel import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://app.wealthcharts.com/')

email = 'joe.weissinger@gmail.com'
passw =  'March12th' 

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//input[@type="email"]').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(passw)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//button[@type="submit"]').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Symbol")]')))

sleep(1)
data=[]
check = []

links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@class="ag-center-cols-container"]/div')
yym = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"]/span')
f = open('data.csv', 'a')
f.write('symbol,name,Time_Announced,Day_Announced,Analyst_Firm,Analyst_Name,Action_on_Security,Prior_Rating,Rating,Action_Price_Target,Prior_Price_Target,Price_Target\n')
for i in links:
    if i in check:
        continue
    try:
        symbol = yym[links.index(i)].text
    except:
        symbol = 'none'
    try :
        name = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[3]').text
    except:
        name = 'none'
    try :
        Time_Announced = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[1]').text
    except:
        Time_Announced = 'none'
    try :
        Day_Announced = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[2]').text
    except:
        Day_Announced = 'none'

    try :
        Analyst_Firm = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[4]').text
    except:
        Analyst_Firm = 'none'

    try :
        Analyst_Name = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[5]').text
    except:
        Analyst_Name = 'none'

    try :
        Action_on_Security = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[6]').text
    except:
        Action_on_Security = 'none'

    try :
        Prior_Rating = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[7]').text
    except:
        Prior_Rating = 'none'

    try :
        Rating = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[8]').text
    except:
        Rating = 'none'

    try :
        Action_Price_Target = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[9]').text
    except:
        Action_Price_Target = 'none'

    try :
        Prior_Price_Target = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[10]').text
    except:
        Prior_Price_Target = 'none'

    try :
        Price_Target = i.find_element(By.XPATH , './/div[11]').text
    except:
        Price_Target = 'none'

    f.write(symbol + ',' + name + ',' + Time_Announced + ',' + Day_Announced + ',' + Analyst_Firm + ',' + Analyst_Name + ',' + Action_on_Security + ',' + Prior_Rating + ',' + Rating + ',' + Action_Price_Target + ',' + Prior_Price_Target + ',' + Price_Target + '\n')
    
    try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)# error shown on this line
    except:
        sleep(5)# time delay to handle the error           
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)
    linksd = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@class="ag-center-cols-container"]/div')
    for j in linksd:
        if j in links or j in check:
            pass
        else:
            links.append(j) #next links to be extracted appending to links
    check.append(i)
    print(links.index(i))
print('Done Extracting')
```

some times 20 rows are extracted and sometimes it goes to 46.
links are being extracted first then same link is used to scroll but error is shown. The same code went to 1000 one time. I dont to why is this happening.

Comment: You should probably include the exception in your post.  In general it will help if you use explicit waits every time you get any webelement.  When using find_elements, remember that even if you check expected condition of presence of all elements, it will only wait until at least one item is there.  Before using find_elements, be sure to include a long enough sleep to wait for all elements to populate.  (Or catch the stale element exception and re-get the array if caught...)  Right now your sleep is before your scroll.  Should be after if scroll triggers an update to the DOM.

Comment: @pcalkins added delay after scroll but keeps looping through same first 20 elements